# developing a portable network analyzer application using pcap

Tags: c++, winpcap, portable-applications

I'm having problems with portability issues while developing a network analyzer application using vc++ 2008.

I'm developing an application that analyzes packets using winpcap. However, recently I've been required that my app should also run on solaris and linux .. what I want to ask that I'm using winpcap functions like PacketOpenAdapter to sniff on an adapter .. do I have to rewrite all the capturing code from start to make it work on operating systems other than windows? shall I only use the pcap.h to make my application portable? do I need to use libpcap? in short, what should I do to make it portable?

thx in advance.

Comment: Using a cross-platform library (like libpcap) is a good start.

Comment: thx .. so if I use libpcap I want won't the same code will work on the well-known Operating systems? I got confused when I read in an answer on another question that "libpcap/WinPcap is a cross-platform library, originally created for BSD UN*X" .. is this true? then why Packet32.c has #include <winsock.h>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I want to ask that I'm using winpcap functions like PacketOpenAdapter to sniff on an adapter .. do I have to rewrite all the capturing code from start to make it work on operating systems other than windows?

You need to use *only* functions that are in `wpcap.dll`; you must not use *any* `packet.dll` functions, unless you don't *need* to use them and the program will still work if you don't use them, in which case use them only on Windows.

In addition, don't use `wpcap.dll` functions that are only available on Windows, such as `pcap_open()`; use only `pcap_open_live()` to open a device on which to capture and use only `pcap_open_offline()` to open saved capture files.

> shall I only use the pcap.h to make my application portable?

Yes.

> do I need to use libpcap?

Use libpcap on UN*X (Solaris, Linux, OS X, *BSD, HP-UX, AIX, etc.), use WinPcap (which is libpcap ported to Windows) on Windows, and use only functions that are available in the versions of libpcap you will be using on UN*X and in the version of WinPcap you're using on Windows.

Then make sure everything *else* you use is either portable between UN*X and Windows or, if you *have* to use platform-specific functions, make sure you use the ones appropriate for a particular platform only on that platform.